# Pandas reindex and assigning Columns to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

I am creating a pandas dataframe and wanting to create a new column by assigning and reindexing method. The way I am doing is to pull the data which may have say 'A', 'B', 'C', D' 'E' columns
and I am wanting to create a new column say 'XX'. ( of course there are other columns in the dataframe and its a huge one, I just show this sample below). XX column is usually the OR logic or max of the columns of A->E

Like

INPUT:

```
     df 
             A   B   C    D   E  
             0   0   1    0   1
             0   0   0    0   0
             1   0   0    0   0
```

OUTPUT:

```
    df
             A   B   C    D   E     XX 
             0   0   1    0   1     1
             0   0   0    0   0     1
             1   0   0    0   0     1
```

So the way I am doing

```
    ICOLS  = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E]

    df = (df.assign(XX=df.reindex(ICOLS, axis=1).dropna().max(axis=1)).dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
```

The script is working fine, but its only working when I have all the columns from A to E. Many times in the database ( say C or E etc is missing) , but I still want to have the same logic and XX should give the similar output.

So if the data base has only A, B & E rows, then:

INPUT:

```
     df 
             A   B   E  
             0   0   1
             0   0   0
             1   0   0
```

OUTPUT:

```
    df
             A   B   E     XX 
             0   0   1     1
             0   0   0     1
             1   0   0     1
```

I am not sure how to acheive that in the way I am doing from the list of the inputCols ICOLS. I will appreciate if a help in the direction in which I am trying to fix. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the expected output for `xx` correct? From the description and example code I would think it should be `0` for the second row in each of the outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a base list of columns, then check if those columns exists in your df:

```
BASE_COLUMNS  = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
available_cols = [column for column in df.columns if column in BASE_COLUMNS]
```

Finally, apply your solution, but now passing `available_cols` as the columns:

```
df = (df.assign(XX=df.reindex(available_cols, axis=1).dropna().max(axis=1)).dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
```

**This will handle the situation when some column is missing**

Comment: absolutely yes! Thanks. Solution accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Do it in one line.

Please filter required columns. Put the columns you need in a list. That will filter them, try find max in each row into a new column and find max in the resultant column

Data

```
 print(df)

   A  B  C   f  D  E
0  0  0  1   2  0  1
1  0  0  0  56  0  0
2  1  0  0  70  0  0
```

Solution;

```
df['xx']=df.filter(items=['A', 'B','E','D']).max(1).max(0)
```

OR

```
ICOLS  = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
df['xx']=df.filter(items=ICOLS).max(1).max(0)
```

print(df)

```
   A  B  C   f  D  E  xx
0  0  0  1   2  0  1   1
1  0  0  0  56  0  0   1
2  1  0  0  70  0  0   1
```

Comment: I did not understand your solution. The basic issue is that many times all the five columns are not there and so I still need to have the XX output with the same logic. When I have all the columns from A& E my code works. But whenever I have one missing column( say C etc), the code fails.

Comment: this will not solve his problem, because he has several columns, and he wants to apply his solutions only on ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E] or any column inside that list

Comment: @ltaljuk  `df['xx']=df.filter(items=['A', 'B','E','D']).max(1).max(0)`

Comment: yes, that will fix the problem, but... what happens when A, B, C, D, OR E is missing???

Answer (score 1):

Note: Using [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) as suggested @wwnde is probably better

If your main problem is to select columns based on the available columns, you could simply look at [df.columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) for the available columns.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     [
...         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
...         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
...         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
...     ],
...     columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
... )
>>> df
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  1  0  1
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0

>>> df.columns
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], dtype='object')
```

Then using a Python `set` you could find the intersection.

```
>>> ICOLS  = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
>>> set(df.columns) & set(ICOLS)
{'D', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'A'}
```

Together that could be:

```
>>> df.assign(XX=df[set(df.columns) & set(ICOLS)].max(1))
   A  B  C  D  E  XX
0  0  0  1  0  1   1
1  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  1  0  0  0  0   1
```

Comment: This works, but a bit more than in the direction where I proceeded. Thanks. This is an alternate solution!